# How to install ssl certificate on aws ec2 apache2 ubuntu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, apache2

Can you refer me to an online guide on "How to install SSL certificates on aws ec2 apache2 ubuntu?"  The Amazon official https/ssl cert documentation is a wild goose chase of wild goose chases.  The instructions are so robust for each and every one of the thousand ways you might go about doing it, that they don't get around to saying how to actually do it.  Following the directions is like trying to thread a needle in a pinball machine.

I have an EC2 instance that runs Apache2 on Ubuntu 14. I already have a domain name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a tutorial which have step by step ssl certificate configuration.

Please check the following 2 link:

1. [Simplest way to Use our SSL Certificates with Amazon EC2 Ubuntu
   Server](https://www.domainsatretail.com/blog/security/simplest-way-use-ssl-certificates-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server/)
2. [Configure Apache Web Server on Amazon Linux to use SSL/TLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html)

Same type of answer is available here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/745408/how-to-enable-ssl-on-ubuntu-apache2-ec2-instance-correctly